# Vertical Align issue in both chrome and moz

Tags: html, css

my sole problem is I want to make inside the menu is in the middle of the div, then I tried to insert vertical align since it is already has inline-block style attribute, but i honestly don't know why. Why the other div is the one who taking effect, instead of the one I mean to.

here is my example:

```css
.content{

 width: 100%;
 height: 90%;
}

.middle{

 position: fixed;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
}

.menu{

 width: 70%;
 height: 80%;
}

.three {

 width: 30%;
}


.six{

 width: 60%;
}

.inline {
 display: inline-block;
}

.h-80{

 height: 80%;
}

.h-100{

 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content middle">
 
 <div class="menu">
  <div class="three inline h-80">
   this is taking effect
  </div>
  <div class="six inline h-100"  style="vertical-align: middle;">
   while I inputing vertical align here
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

you can run the snippet to check the truth of my question, oh and I tried both chrome and moz, both are showing same result. while I am rookie, idk what is happening until 3 hours trying..

Comment: your `.middle` is set to `align-items: center;`, meaning first-level children will be aligned in the middle. Put your `.three` outside `.menu`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vertical-align` is a strange CSS property. I added a border around the `.inline` elements to show the effect.

The second `div` is align centered to the baseline of the parent container. The first has implied `vertical-align: baseline` and it adhers to that.

```css
.content{

 width: 100%;
 height: 90%;
}

.middle{

 position: fixed;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
}

.menu{

 width: 70%;
 height: 80%;
}

.three {

 width: 30%;
}


.six{

 width: 60%;
}

.inline {
 display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.h-80{

 height: 80%;
}

.h-100{

 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content middle">
 
 <div class="menu">
  <div class="three inline h-80">
   this is taking effect
  </div>
  <div class="six inline h-100"  style="vertical-align: middle;">
   while I inputing vertical align here
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

If I put `vertical-align:middle` to both `div`s you see, that the containers are both aligned centered, while the *content* of those `div`s is not.

```css
.content{

 width: 100%;
 height: 90%;
}

.middle{

 position: fixed;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
}

.menu{

 width: 70%;
 height: 80%;
}

.three {

 width: 30%;
}


.six{

 width: 60%;
}

.inline {
 display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.h-80{

 height: 80%;
}

.h-100{

 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content middle">
 
 <div class="menu">
  <div class="three inline h-80" style="vertical-align: middle">
   this is taking effect
  </div>
  <div class="six inline h-100"  style="vertical-align: middle;">
   while I inputing vertical align here
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

You need to set the alignment of the content to center as well. This, alas, cannot be made done with the same technique. For this I would use flexbox with `display: inline-flex; align-items: center`. For alternatives, take a look at this question: [How do I vertically align text in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-in-a-div)

```css
.content{

 width: 100%;
 height: 90%;
}

.middle{

 position: fixed;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
}

.menu{

 width: 70%;
 height: 80%;
}

.three {

 width: 30%;
}


.six{

 width: 60%;
}

.inline {
 display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.inline span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.h-80{

 height: 80%;
}

.h-100{

 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content middle">
 
 <div class="menu">
  <div class="three inline h-80" style="vertical-align: middle">
   this is taking effect
  </div>
  <div class="six inline h-100"  style="vertical-align: middle;">
   while I inputing vertical align here
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And to further adjust: You could drop the inline-block altogether and just use flexbox everywhere

```
.middle, .menu, .three, .six {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
}

.middle, .menu, .three, .six {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.middle {
  position: fixed;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menu {
  width: 70%;
  height: 80%;
}

.three {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: gold;
}

.six {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: silver;
}

.h-80 {
  height: 80%;
}

.h-100 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content middle">

  <div class="menu">
    <div class="three h-80" style="vertical-align: middle">
      this is taking effect
    </div>
    <div class="six h-100" style="vertical-align: middle;">
      while I inputing vertical align here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @hek I added an all-flexbox example to the end of my answer

Answer (score 0):

You just remove position: fixed; form the code it gives same as you want

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu{
    width: 70%;
    height: 80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.three{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 30%;
}

.six{
    width: 60%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

and remove that vertical align.